# Protect application with microsoft azure AD

Tags: php, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-app-api

I build an application with Azure directory.

I created an apps here:

```
https://apps.dev.microsoft.com
```

The problem is: all people can connect to my application with a microsoft account.

it is possible, because the application is in Active Directory, to prevent anyone to connect on my application except people in my active directory?

I tried many apps like [active-directory from magium](https://github.com/magium/active-directory) and other that use active directory with Azure graph API.

should I put a validation after

```
$entity = $ad->authenticate();
```

I work with PHP.

Anyone Know I can fixed it ?

**Update**

Authorization url:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?state=..&scope=..&response_type=code&approval_prompt=auto&client_id=&redirect_uri=...
```

Comment: Can you share how you're creating sign in URL in your application for authenticating the user? Essentially this is the URL your user will be redirected to for authentication.

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace `common` in your sign-in URI with the name of your Azure AD (e.g company.onmicrosoft.com). So part of your sign-in URI would be:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{company.onmicrosoft.com}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?...rest...
```

This would ensure that only users from your Azure AD will be able to sign in. You can read more about the endpoints in Azure AD v2 here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols#endpoints.